# Questions about Java OOP(Inheritence)

Tags: java, object-oriented-analysis

I am trying to make a videogame that is similar to "Turing Complete". In this game you are supposed to connect circuit pieces to create a computer by the end. So I have a question on inheritance. I have a class called "Circuitware" and every object extends this as follows

```java
public Circuitware implements connectable {

    protected int x;
    protected int y;
    protected int allowedConnetions;
    protected Ciruitware[] connections;
    private int totalConnections;

    public Circuitware(int x, int y, int allowedConnections, Circuitware[] connections) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.allowedConnections = allowedConnections;
        this.connections = new Array[allowedConnections];
        for (Object O: connections) {
            if (O != null) {
                this.totalConnections += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
    
    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }
    
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    public<T> void addConnection(T connection) {
        if (this.totalConnections<this.allowedConnections) {
            this.connections.add(connection);
        }
    }
}
```

Now an example of a subclass is

```java
public class LogicGate extends Circuitware {

    String type;

    public LogicGate(int x, int y, int allowedConnections, Circuitware[] connections, String type) {
        super(x, y, allowedConnections, connections);
        this.type = type;
    }

    public boolean output() {
        //Depending on the gate and input we output things
    }

}
```

Now the thing is that the number of allowed connections depends on the type of the circuit, for example logic gates in my game can have 1 connection if it is an NOT gate, 2 connections if it is an AND, XOR, NOR gates or 3 connections if it is and extended OR, extended AND gates, where are switches can only have 0. Is there are better way of doing this?

I also need help understanding that if I have an array of type Circuitware can I add objects from its subclasses? Because the output of logic gates and inputs of other logic gates while they can be inputs to clocks.

Would it be better, design-wise, if I got rid of the "Circuitware" class altogether? But then wouldn't that make connections between different classes harder?

Comment: A `LogicGate` is-a `Circuitware`. It should be straight-forward to test if a collection of `Circuitware` will accept subclasses of `Circuitware`, although most OOP tutorials will explicitly demonstrate whether or not it's possible. Tangential, but a switch with no input isn't a switch, it's a wire.

Comment: Usually, you don't initialize an array by calling new Array[] but by the used type. In this case it would be `new Circuitware[allowedConnections];`

Comment: A Circuitware super class for all components is perfectly fine. My two cents would be to make both Circuitware and LogicGate abstract, because you don't want instances of those classes to be created. And the array of your connections  doesn't provide you any information which sides are connected to what. Or is it more of an list of inputting-connections?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.